# Unwanted results with REGEXP, MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I am not good with REGEX, Can someone help me with optimizing my MySQL query, please?

```
SELECT activity
FROM activity
WHERE (LOWER( activity_name ) REGEXP '>mit|mit,|edited mit')
ORDER BY created_date DESC
```

When I replace `'>mit|mit,|edited mit'` with `'mit|mit,|edited mit'`, It works so fast but It displays additional records which are not needed. I tried even `'/[>]/mit|mit,|edited mit'`, unfortunately, I got wrong result.

Thank you

Comment: `>mit|mit,|edited mit` should be `^mit|mit,|edited mit`?

Comment: Or maybe: `^(mit|mit,|edited mit)`. It would be helpful if you would explain what you want to match, and which results you get, and which you don't want.

Comment: No, I wrote it correctly, those are href links. So I am matching with closing angle bracket and the link initials. Thanks though.

Comment: Frankly speaking, your pattern is quite optimal. If you remove the first `>` there appear two alternatives that match at the same location and that is usually worsening performance. What you might want is to lessen the number of alternatives, or get rid of them completely. If you tried `'mit|mit,|edited mit'`, then it makes sense to write it as `'mit,?|edited mit'` and that means you may reduce it to `'(edited )?mit'`. Maybe just `LIKE '%mit%'` will be enough?

Comment: Please provide examples and counter examples. The question is apparently not about performance or optimisation, but unwanted results.

Comment: I am sorry trincot, you are right. @wiktor I have optimized my query by replacing "like" statements with REGEXP, Saved 30% of search time. I am trying to save more. It takes 12 seconds to search 2K records now, it was a lot before with like statements even after indexing. Can you please help me with the REGEX to match a string like "<Andrew> Robert"? Please do not ignore my angle brackets. I think that is what I am looking to satisfy the requirement.

Comment: @Mitul `REGEXP '^<[[:alnum:]]+>[[:blank:]]+[[:alnum:]]+$'`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the reason for the burst of speed in the second regexp was that things had been cached by the first test.  Did you try both regexps twice?

This should be a little better:

```
WHERE activity_name LIKE '%mit%'
  AND LOWER( activity_name ) REGEXP '>mit|mit,|edited mit'
```

`LIKE` is faster than `REGEXP`, but not nearly as powerful.  So, the `LIKE` will filter out most rows, then the `REGEXP` will finish the filtering.

Another slight speedup:  If `activity_name` has a `..._ci` collation, you don't need `LOWER()`.

Even faster would be to have a `FULLTEXT` index and do

```
WHERE MATCH(activity_name) AGAINST('+mit' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND REGEXP '>mit|mit,|edited mit'
```